# CSS help adding PNG in front of background?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm making a personal website and I will need some help with the navigation bar on the side of my webpage. Basically, this is the code I've got for my background:

```
html { 
            background: url(index_bg.PNG) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
         }
```

The background and everything else is fine but I would like to have 4 pictures (PNGs) to be aligned on the side of my webpage to act as a simple navigation bar. This will have to be on top of my background and I will add links to the pictures later so they become clickable icons. But the issue is this, I can't seem to figure out how to add the images as another layer on top of the background (they just go above the background instead).

Thanks in advance for taking your time to read this post and answering it.

- Ryan

Comment: just use img tag for your 4 images, and when you want to add links wrap them in an a tag

Comment: Could you give us a jsfiddle of your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/54r0vk8L/

```css
html {
  background: url(http://www.greenhdwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/grass-pictures-free-6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
img {
    width:175px;
    height:125px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Animals/Cats/cats-54a.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://cattpix.com/file/2013/11/cute-cat-wallpaper.jpg"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://inspirekids.designdecor.in/kids/cute-cat/cute-cat-pic-8.jpg"></a>
```

And you can edit the spacing (e.g. from the left hand edge if you want the pictures flush, and below and above each picture if you want a gap.)

Comment: Very welcome :) Any chance you could accept it? @RyanWee Merry Christmas